# How to apply placeholder when image height is 0 in nextjs13

Tags: next.js

```
    <Image
      src={props.src}
      alt={alt}
      width={width}
      height={0}
      blurDataURL={blurImageUrl}
      placeholder="blur"
      style={{
        maxWidth: '100%',
        height: 'auto',
        display: 'block',
        margin: '40px auto 10px',
      }}
    />
```

We are currently planning to apply blur in the placeholder option to prevent image layout shifts. But right now, my image is `objectfill:cover` after applying only width, as shown below. Since the height is 0, applying placeholder doesn't work properly, is there any workaround?